# Github actions automated unit tests failing with "cannot find module 'aws-exports'"

Tags: testing, github-actions, aws-amplify, aws-config

I am trying to find a way to run unit tests automatically on a project hosted by amplify using Github Actions to trigger the unit tests on pull request.

On each instance of the action, it is failing on line

```
import awsconfig from 'aws-exports';
```

With the error:

```
Cannot find module 'aws-exports' from 'src/resource/utils/HttpMethods.js'
```

The issue seems to be that the aws-exports file is generated by Amplify at build time, however, since these test are being run on github when a PR is created, Amplify has not yet built out and has not generated the aws-exports file.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to want to run automated unit tests for an Amplify hosted site. Has anyone encountered this issue/found a solution?

My github action for reference:

```
name: Node CI

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: yarn install
    - run: yarn test
```

I have already tried removing the aws-exports from the gitignore and manually posting it to the repo. This worked but is not ideal since amplify will re-generate this file on build.

*edit*
My current (working?) solution is to create a dummy config file for each environment, which contains the contents that the aws-exports would contain if it had built. I import this file instead of aws-exports.
While this solution "works" for now, it feels flimsy, and I would much rather have a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the [amplify-cli-action](https://github.com/ambientlight/amplify-cli-action) to configure amplify in my GitHub Actions.

Note: I had to make a minor update to the default example to include `amplify_cli_version: 10.6.1` as described in a workaround to this issue: https://github.com/ambientlight/amplify-cli-action/issues/31

```
name: Build/Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      - run: npm install
      - name: configure amplify
        uses: ambientlight/amplify-cli-action@0.3.0
        with:
          amplify_command: configure
          amplify_env: dev
          amplify_cli_version: 10.6.1
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_REGION: us-west-2
      - run: npm test
```